# I Can't open onion sites with Tor on Chrome

Tags: chrome

I've configured tor to use on chrome setting chrome to use socks. When I go to the site https://check.torproject.org/ it says "Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor. However, it does not appear to be Tor Browser." in yellow, and I can't open any onion sites (I've already checked they're working, just not working on chrome)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use Chrome instead of the Tor Browser? You're sure they're working on the Tor Browser? Have you followed a particular set of instructions?

Comment: The scary answer might be that Chrome isn't using Tor for resolving site addresses. If it's leaking DNS, .onion sites should not resolve and might explain this behaviour. Chrome is leaky, it will leak under certain conditions and potentially harm you.